# azure file upload from client side

Tags: javascript, azure, cors, media, azure-media-services

```
reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
        if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2

            submitUri = "https://mediasvclb3ql3sjdqfh8.blob.core.windows.net/asset-4205a03a-0d00-80c4-6d1d-f1e5bd379a7f/sample.mp4?sv=2012-02-12&sr=c&si=180e3bdd-0856-4001-85b5-9aa455505ca3&sig=y0PFiMampL7sscrdcxcm4itTHNNeXhVc0JJGxFNiVuc%3D&st=2016-01-17T18%3A05%3A20Z&se=2115-12-24T18%3A05%3A20Z";
            // var uri = submitUri;
            var uri = submitUri; //+ '&comp=block&blockid=' + blockIds[blockIds.length - 1];
            var requestData = new Uint8Array(evt.target.result);

            $.ajax({
                url: uri,
                type: "PUT",
                data: requestData,
                processData: false,
                beforeSend: function(xhr) {

                    xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type',    'application/octet-stream');
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-version',    '2014-02-14');
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-blob-type',  'BlockBlob');


                    // xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Length', requestData.length);
                },
                success: function (data, status) {
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(status);
                    bytesUploaded += requestData.length;
                    var percentComplete = ((parseFloat(bytesUploaded) / parseFloat(selectedFile.size)) * 100).toFixed(2);
                    $("#fileUploadProgress").text(percentComplete + " %");
                    uploadFileInBlocks();
                },
                error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
                    console.log(desc);
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

[image]

[image]

I made this from the sample [here](http://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/16/uploading-large-files-in-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-shared-access-signature-html-and-javascript/)

I also enable CORS for this account [image]

You can run the code http://megamedia.cloudapp.net/uploader.html

**what I am doing wrong ? Why my file is not uploading ?**

Comment: You're getting a `Resource Not Found (404)` error. Can you please check if the blob container (`asset-4205a03a-0d00-80c4-6d1d-f1e5bd379a7f`) exists in your storage account?

Comment: yes it exist ... https://mediasvclb3ql3sjdqfh8.blob.core.windows.net/asset-4205a03a-0d00-80c4-6d1d-f1e5bd379a7f/sample.mp4?sv=2012-02-12&sr=c&si=180e3bdd-0856-4001-85b5-9aa455505ca3&sig=y0PFiMampL7sscrdcxcm4itTHNNeXhVc0JJGxFNiVuc%3D&st=2016-01-17T18%3A05%3A20Z&se=2115-12-24T18%3A05%3A20Z

Comment: I an using this link for upload

Answer (score 2):

I have reproduced the issue from my side. It turns out that you didn't specified sufficient permissions to your SAS token. For upload operation, you need to specify "**sp=rw**" permission in you SAS token. 
Please check this article for details:https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/

Below is my test just for your reference:

**Scenario 1**: Generate SAS token without write permission.

https://.blob.core.windows.net/test1/sample.mp4?sv=2014-02-14&sr=c&sig=XnmDhSnec43Mm06tXtRoqJu8r3CPFXYbzE5%2FJW9c27Q%3D&st=2016-01-18T16%3A00%3A00Z&se=2016-01-26T16%3A00%3A00Z&***sp=r***

I get the same 404 result as yours: 
[image]

**Scenario 2**: Generate SAS token with write permission.

https://.blob.core.windows.net/test1/sample.mp4?sv=2014-02-14&sr=c&sig=vOYJfGN%2F0TJrgoIoiYqLWm%2FF7A4dkhrDyUChQlVbUN0%3D&st=2016-01-18T16%3A00%3A00Z&se=2016-01-26T16%3A00%3A00Z&***sp=rw***

[image]

Please note the param "sp" specified in the SAS token, ***sp=r*** means you have only read permission to this token, ***sp=rw*** mean read&write permission. Hope this help you.

Edit:
Just share the tool [Azure Storage Explorer 6](https://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/releases/view/125870) which can easily generate an SAS token.

Comment: I used Azure Storage Explorer 6 and generate this string http://mediasvclb3ql3sjdqfh8.blob.core.windows.net/blobhobeto?sv=2014-02-14&sr=c&sig=mc9W0quwlvqHlSZMXU80SF1YEpPLaubndT4zRS78AAM%3D&st=2016-01-19T08%3A00%3A00Z&se=2016-01-27T08%3A00%3A00Z&sp=rw

Comment: But this url still has a same issue

Comment: @Anri I just tried uploading files to the new SAS url you provided and it works without any problem, you can verify it from your side(you could see some files named stars.jpg in "blobhobeto" container). So the new URL seems correct to me. You mentioned that this url still has a same issue, did you mean you still get 404 error when uploading to this url from your side? I've noticed the code you shared is a little different from the original sample, but even when I modify the code as yours, it still works fine from my side.

Comment: Is it considered good practice to upload a file directly from the client to azure or is it safer to just drop it in my server first?